# Creating smartbanner with jquery.smartabnner on android firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, mobile

I use jquery.smartbanner to show smartbanners on mobile website. It works for ios, windows phone and android default browser. But when checking it with Firefox on android then I do not see smartbanner. I was checking it as well on Firefox with user agent switcher and when I set user agent to:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Android; Linux armv7l; rv:9.0) Gecko/20111216 Firefox/9.0 Fennec/9.0
```

Which pretends to be android Firefox then I can see results. The problem only appears on mobile firefox. What kind of User Agent is this browser using? Maybe I use incorrect one.

I use jquery 1.7.2 with smartbanner.

I also user following script to enable banner:

```
$.smartbanner({
    hideOnInstall: false, // Hide the banner after "VIEW" is clicked.
    author: "ddd", // What the author of the app should be in the banner (defaults to <meta name="author"> or hostname)
    appendToSelector: '#appBanner', //Append the banner to a specific selector
    daysHidden: 0, // Duration to hide the banner after being closed (0 = always show banner)
    daysReminder: 0, // Duration to hide the banner after "VIEW" is clicked *separate from when the close button is clicked* (0 = always show banner)
    button: 'ZOBACZ', // Text for the install button
    price: 'DARMOWY', // Price of the app
    inAppStore: 'w App Store', // Text of price for iOS
    inGooglePlay: 'w Google Play', // Text of price for Android
    inWindowsStore: 'w the Windows Store', //Text of price for Windows
    icon: "{{ STATIC_URL }}/mobile/images/multiapp.png"
})
```

**EDIT 1:**

Are there any tools to debugging js with firefox on android?

Comment: You can remotely debug FF Android using Desktop Firefox: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Znj_8IFeTVs

Comment: @FrancescoMM Great I will check this one.

Comment: Haha, maybe I should write it as an answer and grab the bounty! :) Have you solved the issue?

Comment: Not yet, I have other things to do :) But I believe you have earned it. Add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

To remotely debug Firefox Android using Desktop Firefox you can follow this simple and clear tutorial:

http://youtube.com/watch?v=Znj_8IFeTVs

:)